# VS Code Prettier Format On Save stopped working with latest update Oct 2020

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

My VS Code setting is

```json
{
   "editor.formatOnSave": true,
}
```

It was working previously, but after the recent update, it stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the VS Code setting

File -> Preferences -> Settings (for Windows)

Code -> Preferences -> Settings (for Mac)

Search for "Default Formatter". In the dropdown, prettier will show as `esbenp.prettier-vscode`

[image: Screenshot]

For more details kindly check this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108447)